# Reference controls (Table) dynamically in code behinde

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I would like to know if it is possible to fill different tables with one *foreach*.

I have 5 table´s *tbl0, tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4* and at the moment i use the code below one time per table.

```
//fill *dtTable* with SQL

foreach (DataRow dr in dtTable.Rows)
{         
   TableHeaderRow tHRow = new TableHeaderRow();
   TableHeaderCell tHeader = new TableHeaderCell();
   tHeader.Text = dr.Field<string>("Loc");
   tHRow.Cells.Add(tHeader);
   tbl0.Rows.Add(tHRow);

   //fill 'hl' with sql

   tCell.Controls.Add(hl);
   tRow.Controls.Add(tCell);
   tbl0.Rows.Add(tRow);
}
```

I thougt of something like:

```
 //fill *dtTable* with SQL    

 int i = 0;
 foreach (DataRow dr in dtTable.Rows)
 {         
    string TABLENAME = "tbl"+i; 

    TableHeaderRow tHRow = new TableHeaderRow();
    TableHeaderCell tHeader = new TableHeaderCell();
    tHeader.Text = dr.Field<string>("Loc");
    tHRow.Cells.Add(tHeader);

    (Table)this.FindControl(TABLENAME).Rows.Add(tHRow); // does not funktion, just an idea

    //fill 'hl' with sql

    tCell.Controls.Add(hl);
    tRow.Controls.Add(tCell);

    (Table)this.FindControl(TABLENAME).Rows.Add(tRow); // does not funktion, just an idea
    i++;
}
```

How can i have an sort of dynamic *TableName* so i wont need the same code five times?

Comment: Doing this with a `foreach` would be a tad clunky. Why are you trying to avoid a `for` loop? I'm assuming each table has the same number of rows.

Comment: every table can have a different amount of rows and every DataRow creates a table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach:

```
int i = 0;
var tables = new List<Table>();
tables.Add(tbl0);
tables.Add(tbl1);
tables.Add(tbl2);
tables.Add(tbl3);
tables.Add(tbl4);


foreach (DataRow dr in dtTable.Rows)
{   
    // validation
   if(i>tables.Count)
   {
      return;
   }

   var tbl in tables[i];
   TableHeaderRow tHRow = new TableHeaderRow();
   TableHeaderCell tHeader = new TableHeaderCell();
   tHeader.Text = dr.Field<string>("Loc");
   tHRow.Cells.Add(tHeader);

   tbl.Rows.Add(tHRow);

   //fill 'hl' with sql

   tCell.Controls.Add(hl);
   tRow.Controls.Add(tCell);

   tbl.Rows.Add(tRow);
   i++;
}
```

I don't like to use `(Table)this.FindControl(TABLENAME).Rows.Add(tRow);` because maybe in the future you will change the id of the tables so you will have to change the function as well.

Comment: this won´t work, every DataRow in the foreach should "create" a table

Comment: I assumed from your code ("(Table)this.FindControl(TABLENAME).Rows.Add(tRow)") that tables are already created.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. First DataRow corresponds with tbl0, the second datarow with tbl1 and so on... Right? or I missed something?

Comment: Right ! thats how it should work. I´m not that good at explaining :/

Comment: Than you should consider to validate the position of the current table. If dtTable has 10 rows you will get an error because you don't have tables[10]. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to ensure you're not needing repeat the same code would be to iterate over all of your tables as well.

```
foreach (var table in new [] {tbl0, tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4}) {
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows) {         
        string TABLENAME = "tbl"+i; 

        TableHeaderRow tHRow = new TableHeaderRow();
        TableHeaderCell tHeader = new TableHeaderCell();
        tHeader.Text = dr.Field<string>("Loc");
        tHRow.Cells.Add(tHeader);

        (Table)this.FindControl(TABLENAME).Rows.Add(tHRow);

        //fill 'hl' with sql

        tCell.Controls.Add(hl);
        tRow.Controls.Add(tCell);

        (Table)this.FindControl(TABLENAME).Rows.Add(tRow);
        i++;
    }
}
```